# How do I change my Slack bot icon in python?

Tags: python-3.x, slack, slack-api

I'm very (very) novice at playing with the Slack api - so be gentle and use short words. So far I have managed to set up a simple system that can post to our Slack channel. All well and good, but the icon associated with the posts is the default. How do I go about setting a different icon or even one I create myself?

Here is the basic code (snagged from a tutorial listed on teh Slack api dev site):

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage'
token = 'xoxb-00000000000etc'


headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(token)}

def send_message(message_text):
    message = {'channel': '#channel_name', 'text': message_text}
    requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(message))

send_message('beep boop - this is the OMS bot calling')
```

Many thanks...

Answer (score 5):

To set the icon image for your message you can simple provide the property `icon_url` with a URL to an image.

Example:

```
message = {'channel': '#channel_name', 'text': message_text, 'icon_url': 'https://img.icons8.com/emoji/96/000000/penguin--v2.png'}
```

You can see all available properties on the official documentation page for the API method [chat.postMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage).

Since you said you very a beginner allow me to make two additional suggestions.

### 1 - The offical Slack library

There is an official Slack library for Python which makes thinks much easier, e.g. you don't need to deal with the requests library and HTTP headers. You find it here: https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient

## 2 - Slack token in environment variables

For security reasons it is good practice to put your slack token in an environment variable. That way you also can check in your code into github etc.

### Updated example

Here is your example with the two suggested improvements:

```
import slack
import os

client = slack.WebClient(token=os.environ['SLACK_TOKEN'])

response = client.chat_postMessage(        
    channel='general',
    text='beep boop - this is the OMS bot calling',
    icon_url='https://img.icons8.com/emoji/96/000000/penguin--v2.png'
)
```

Comment: Awesome. If this answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

When passing `icon_url` or `icon_emoji` to a bot, remember that [the scope `chat:write.customize` is required](https://api.slack.com/scopes/chat:write.customize). Otherwise it will have no effect.

Comment: Thanks, I was going mad with this. For anyone else that is trying to put "icon_emoji" at all levels in their json. It works at the same level as 'channel' and 'blocks', but without this permission it does nothing.